# Hyperlink returned results from one column to another column

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, hyperlink

This project is essential a catalog of past projects/designs that I use at work. Currently it puts the clickable link to a PDF of the proof file in the Link column and labels them all "PDF". I'd like to change the output to make the "Client Name" column clickable, and their hyperlinks direct to the PDFs from the Link column instead. I believe I've located the correct section in the code to modify, but how do I print the returned value for the Link column PDF, as a hyperlink, using the returned value for the Client Name column as its plain text name? Here is the section of code I suspect needs to be modified, and then there is a screenshot of how it looks now. Any pointers on what direction I could take would be greatly appreciated!

The Code:

```
$registrantList = '';
$sql = "SELECT Client, Product, Market, Type, Date, Category, Disc, Link, Notes FROM designarchive ORDER BY $sql_orderBy";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$registrantList .= '<tr><td>' . htmlentities($row['Client']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Product']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Market']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Type']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Date']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Category']) . '</td><td>' . $row['Disc'] . '</td><td><a href="' . $row['Link'] . '">PDF</a></td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Notes']) . '</td></tr>';
}
```

The Screenshot:
[the screenshot http://chicofunnyfaces.com/soada/scratch/desarch_links_problem.jpg](http://chicofunnyfaces.com/soada/scratch/desarch_links_problem.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to this:

```
$registrantList .= '<tr><td><a href="' . $row['Link'] . '">' . htmlentities($row['Client']) . '</a></td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Product']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Market']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Type']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Date']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Category']) . '</td><td>' . $row['Disc'] . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($row['Notes']) . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: and look in your code where you define the table and remove the pdf table header

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help. I'm still learning and the ' " '. . ' "  ' structure has been really difficult to wrap my head around, but I believe I understand what you did there. That now links the Client column with the appropriate PDF. [image](http://chicofunnyfaces.com/soada/scratch/desarch_links_fixed.jpg)

Comment: may a good way to start for you to learn the basic syntax ;) [PHP Language Reference and Basic Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php)